# Encrypting data for RESTful services using Jersey

Tags: java, security, rest, soap, jersey

I am using Jersey for my RESTful web service development. I already have configured SSL for Point to Point security...but I need some application level security (end to end), for which I guess encryption is the only way to go. Are there some encryption features in-built with Jersey for encrypting the XML/JSON I am sending to my clients ? Or maybe a third-party Java filter which can help me in this case ??

If I get nothing, I guess I may have to write code for encrypting the objects before serializing it into XML/JSON through Jersey...but I guess this would be painful and far less efficient.

Any thoughts would be appreciated on this topic. I want my RESTful services to be as secure as those offered by the SOAP WS Security standards.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: So, you're encrypting the data on the wire using SSL, but you also want to encrypt the data which you're going to encrypt? What is the problem you're trying to solve by doing that? Does your application need access to the data within the XML/JSON payloads or not?

Comment: I am also looking for application level security, not only the transport level security. By what I have been reading over web, SSL does not offer end-to-end security (app. level) : http://serverfault.com/questions/277644/ssl-point-to-point-security-vs-end-to-end-security

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "application level security". Are you trying to prevent snooping of your databases? Your logs? Your processes?

Comment: I produced the term here as I saw over the web ! I just need to secure the data I sent in a fashion that only the destined "application" (and not the "system") is able to use the data my client sends. This is because I need to pass on this data between many intermediaries which may/not use SSL.

Comment: So what you're trying to do is prevent snooping of your data as it moves between your application layers, right? Then you need to insist that SSL be used to encrypt the data as it moves between each tier of your application. If you can't make that happen, you'll end up re-implementing SSL-like functionality within your application, making it more complex and harder to maintain. It would be far better to enforce a secure transport between each tier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why SSL alone doesn't meet your needs (isn't "point to point" the same thing as "end to end"?) but [the Keyczar encryption library](http://www.keyczar.org/) (open sourced by Google) looks very easy to use.

Comment: I read on many forums that SSL does not provide end to end security : http://serverfault.com/questions/277644/ssl-point-to-point-security-vs-end-to-end-security

Comment: Read [the first answer to the question you linked to](http://serverfault.com/questions/277644/ssl-point-to-point-security-vs-end-to-end-security/277786#277786) which clarifies that the original poster is confused by an article discussing relaying of data, which his question (and yours) is not concerned with. If you use SSL between your service and a client, then everything between your service and the client is encrypted over the wire. If your service needs to relay requests from the client to other services and uses SSL only from client to server, then no the entire thing is not encrypted.

Comment: In a system where there is only one system talking to another system, then "point to point" and "end to end" means the same thing, as the "points" and "ends" are identical.

Comment: I am sorry for not clarifying initially. I have a list of intermediaries for the message transmission, which may or may not use HTTPS. In the link I postd above, it is clear that I have to have an application level encryption for such case.

Comment: Ah that wasn't clear initially. If you truly need to encrypt the payload yourself, then I think keyczar or bouncycastle (suggested below) should work fine, no?

Comment: Yes, I guess I have to go with these tools. I just thought maybe Jersey offers some easy way (without writing extra code in all my classes) to do this - or maybe some filters.

Comment: @WinOrWin - Libraries such as Jersey are not going to incorporate encryption such as you need simply because it would be used so seldom as most people can just use https.  What you are using will be more complex due to the max length of urls, if that becomes an issue.

Comment: @matt b : I am going for Keyczar :) But I do you think this would work good for my mobile clients such as iPhone and Blackberry ?

Comment: @WinOrWin - It may work on the iPhone, though you will probably need to wrap the C++. Doubt it will work on the Blackberry unless they have a JavaME version.  BouncyCastle has a JavaME version, so you can get it to work on Blackberries and Android but not the iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

If you are having to put everything on the URL for your RESTful service then you will probably run into a limit on how long the url can be when you encrypt.

I tend to use BouncyCastle (http://www.bouncycastle.org/) for my encryption, but that is because they support Java and .NET.

But, why are you concerned that SSL may not be enough security?

If the concern is that you want to verify whom sent it then you may want to just have the sender create a digital signature and append that, so that you can verify their signature.

Comment: Thanks James. Can you please explain the last para of your answer..it is not clear, but seems useful for my case.

Comment: @WinOrWin - Since I didn't realize that there would be other stages the data goes through, my thought was that you wanted to encrypt to verify the sender.  In that case you could concatenate the parameters, then get a digital signature from that, so only the sender could have created it, but anyone could verify that nothing in the parameters was changed by checking the signature.  So it tells you two things, the sender is whom you think it is and no data was changed since it was sent.

Comment: Thank you James. I would try to incorporate this idea too.